# Consumer-/Producer-Pattern with priorities

Tags: java

A design-question: We had an existing interface (and working implementation) like this one:

```
public interface Service {
   CompletableFuture<ResponseCar> getResponseOfApple(String url, UUID id);
   CompletableFuture<ResponsePear> getResponseOfPear(String url, UUID id);
}
```

The implementation of that will simply return the `CompletableFuture` of a `OkHttp`-Client.

Now we have a new requirement: Hold all possible returns in cache (because the reponses are JSON-objects from a REST-API). We want to cache all `Apple`s and `Pear`s with background-worker which only updates all of them recurrent.

But when the user want a `Pear` that not in cache yet, then this task has a higher priorty as the background-task.

My idea was a `PriorityBlockingQueue` over a type like this:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PrioritizedQueueElement extends Observable implements Comparable<PrioritizedQueueElement> {

    @NonNull
    @Getter
    private final Object argument;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Object returnValue;

    @NonNull
    @Getter
    private final QueueElementType priority;


    @Override
    public int compareTo(final PrioritizedQueueElement o) {
        if (o == null || this.priority == null || o.priority == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("wrong value");
        }

        return this.priority.compareTo(o.priority);
    }


    public <T> T getValue() {
        return (T) this.returnValue;
    }

    public void setReturnValue(final Object value) {
        this.returnValue = value;
        this.setChanged();
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
}

public enum QueueElementType {
    ONE_TIME_HIGH_PRIORITY,
    ONE_TIME_LOW_PRIORITY,
    RECURRENT_HIGH_PRIORITY,
    RECURRENT_LOW_PRIORITY
}
```

### The question(s)

How can achieve that the new implementation implements the old interface? I tried to make the `PrioritizedQueueElement` as `Observable` but dont know how to come from a `Observable` to a `CompletableFuture`?
Or is my design-idea a terrible wrong way?

Comment: Why is there a sudden requirement for this to become `Observable`? Your new service will be what manages the queue and, in a retrieval operation, retrieves values from either the cache or REST as appropriate. Each retrieval operation should be an Element in that queue, or updates to existing data could be queued separately on a lower priority if it isn't imperative to return fresh data anyway.

Comment: Building on that, if not cached, request live data immediately and wait for it to arrive (with 'immediate' priority on a dedicated connection pool). Put result in cache. Separate worker to update existing cached values. Background worker could pause while live retrievals in progress, use separate connection pool, etc.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul No, there is no sudden requirement for `Observable`. I thought it will be easy to turn a `Obserable` into a `CompletableFuture`.